# Yii2 upload field always empty when ajax validation

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2, image-uploading

I have problem with upload file. I use kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput extension. Here my code:

form model rule

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['image'], 'required', 'on' => static::SCENARIO_CREATE],
        [['image'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg', 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024],
    ];
}
```

form view

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([     
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']
]); ?>

 <?= $form->field($model, 'image')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
            'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*'],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'showPreview' => false,
                'showCaption' => true,
                'showRemove' => true,
                'showUpload' => false,
                'showCancel' => false
            ],            
        ]); ?>
```

controller action

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new ItemForm();
    $model->scenario = ItemForm::SCENARIO_CREATE;

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');

        $randomString = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString(10);
        $name = Inflector::slug($model->title) . '_' . $randomString . '.' . $image->extension;

        $url = Image::URL . $name;

        $model->image = $name;          

        if ($model->save()) {
            $image->saveAs($url);
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }       
    } else {         
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,             
        ]);
    }
}
```

Always when I submit form, I got error "image field is required". I have read many tutorials but still I have the same problem when I using ajax validation. Can anyone look at it and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: i added an answer see if that helps you out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Above all you should not use `enableAjaxValidation` option if you have a file type field in your form. see this [**`ISSUE`**](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6873) use `enableClientValidation` instead

Apart from that looking at your complete model it looks like you are trying to use the database table field `image` as the same field to upload images where as you should not do that you should declare a custom field inside your model and use it to upload the file and assign the new filename to the database field `image` currently you have to do some additions in your model and changes to the code

**1.** Declare a custom field with the name `$file` like below on top of your model after `public $tags` like this, `public $myFile;`

**2.** Change your  validation rule

```
[['image'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg', 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024],
```

to the following

```
[['myFile'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg', 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024],
```

and

```
[['image'], 'required', 'on' => static::SCENARIO_CREATE],
```

to this

```
[['myFile','image'], 'required', 'on' => static::SCENARIO_CREATE],
```

**3.** Change your field name in the html form, from `image` to `myFile` i.e `$form->field($model, 'image')` to `$form->field($model, 'myFile')`.

**4.** For changes inside the `action` and `uploadItemImage()` function see below i have updated them.

---

you are assigning the `$name` variable to the `$model->image` field

```
 $model->image = $name;
```

and in the `$name` it is a string, whereas in the model it should be a file

```
 $name = Inflector::slug($model->title) . '_' . $randomString . '.' . $image->extension;
```

what you should be doing is assign the instance of the uploaded file to the model field `image` and then call the `$model->save()` and use the custom filename to `saveAs()`, change your `action` code to the following

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new ItemForm();
    $model->scenario = ItemForm::SCENARIO_CREATE;

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $model->myFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'myFile');
        $randomString = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString(10);
        $model->image = Inflector::slug($model->title) . '_' . $randomString . '.' . $model->myFile->extension;

        $model->uploadItemImage();
        if ($model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }       
    } else {         
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,             
        ]);
    }
}
```

and then create the following method inside your model

```
public function uploadItemImage(){
    $url = Image::URL . $this->image;
    if(!$this->myFile->saveAs($url)){
       $this->addError('myFile','Unable to save the uploaded file');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Muhammad, thank you for your answer. Your code is great, but still I have validation error 'image field is required'. I thing that problem is in kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput extension. Its make hidden input with name 'image' and it is always empty.

Comment: there was still a mistake `$this->saveAs()` should be `$this->image->saveAs()`, and I have implemented it the same way I am also using this plugin, try logging here on the site by signing up with Facebook and try changing your profile picture http://potentialpads.idowstech.com, ideally when working with images I make a model separate for upload images or files. you are not doing it separately can you show your complete model code @Roboto6_1on

Comment: and i suspect that you have a field in your DB table with the name image?

Comment: here you have all my model form: https://paste.ofcode.org/tufSRbr2WPXKxX58bDhVPB |

in DB I have `'image' => $this->string(),`

Comment: you cannot map or apply validation to the database field instead you have to declare a custom field inside the model see my edit for details @Roboto6_1on

Comment: thank you for help and tutorial by step step by step but still I have the same problem :(  I apologize for the problems but can you last time look at this, maybe you will see what I doing wrong. 

+ form view: https://paste.ofcode.org/PWAs94WAb8GSPLQQFMfukw 

+ form model: https://paste.ofcode.org/qTCiYiPemndubEuqd9uKAh

+ action controller: https://paste.ofcode.org/A46FddEDp7KvU5QYfDhYv6

Comment: for once only just remove the `required` section for the `image` and `file` in the model `rules`, just comment out and check if it all works correctly ?

Comment: when I removed `required` from rules all form works correctly.

Comment: okay revert it and now just keep `myFile` field in the required rule and remove the `image` field from it , it should work

Comment: `[['myFile'], 'required', 'on' => static::SCENARIO_CREATE],` still the same problem :(

Comment: okay one last try remove the `required` rule section altogether, and add the `'skipOnEmpty' => false,` like this  `[['myFile'], 'file','skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg', 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024]` @Roboto6_1on

Comment: now we have new validation errror "Please upload the file"

Comment: this  is ridiculous give me some time i just came back home let me replicate everything on my local pc then we will sort it out @Roboto6_1on

Comment: i just replicated everything and it just works fine at my end that is strange the only difference is i didn't provide `enctype` for the form it is added automatically by `fileInput` plugin see the images here [Model](https://imgur.com/a/u3Ju6) , [ControllerAction](https://imgur.com/a/I6N8s) , [form](https://imgur.com/a/WYyaX) , [validationForm-Frontend](https://imgur.com/a/hEDAd) , [DB-saved](https://imgur.com/a/GnR0r) compare the difference and remove the `encType` dclared inside you `ActiveForm` declaration. @Roboto6_1on

Comment: can you add a custom validation function to your model and use ajax validation? I thing you will have the same problem as me

Comment: @Roboto6_1on looks like it won't work with `ajaxValidation` you are right somehow ,see this issue [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6873)

Comment: thank you Muhamman for you work and time to try resolve my problem. In this case I won't use ajax validation :P

Comment: haha :D @Roboto6_1on no issues what was bugging me is that i used it so many places and never faced such issue , i updated my answer too, good luck