# Yii2 AJAX model validation ActiveForm

Tags: validation, model, yii2, active-form

When we are configuring Ajax validation for ActiveForm (for entire form) we can find it difficulty with input validation when our model looks like this:

```
[['file'],'file','skipOnEmpty'=>false,'extensions'=>['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'pdf'],'checkExtensionByMimeType'=>false,'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 2,'message'=>'Wrong format'],
```

It is not recommended to use AJAX for entire form when we have file input.

In this particular situation AJAX will return error in validation even when our file is correctly selected. Way to do it correctly I will describe in answer.

NOTE: This solution is not using external widget like yii2-widget-fileinput for examle, just standard Yii2 file input in ActiveForm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 upload field always empty when ajax validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48157030/yii2-upload-field-always-empty-when-ajax-validation)

Comment: it is not recommended to use `enableAjaxValidation` options for `ActiveForm` when dealing with file uploads.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to describe this process in really basic way.

First we need to decide what fields we are going to validate on client side(We don't need ajax here) and server side(ajax is coming here).

AJAX validation we are going to use mostly for unique fields like login/email. Other fields client side validation is sufficient.

Active From:

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin(
      [
        'id' => 'form-signup',
        'options' => ['encytype' => 'multipart/form-data'],
        'validateOnBlur' => false,
        'enableClientValidation' => true,
        'validationUrl' => Url::toRoute('customer/validation')
      ]
    );
?>
```

validationUrl -> Url to action in controller, in my case this is CustomerController and actionValidation.

In controller:

```
    public function actionValidation() {
    $model = new Customer();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
}
```

Field in form that we really need to validate using AJAX

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'email', ['enableAjaxValidation' => true])->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

Comment: this is totally wrong , you cannot use and shouldnt use `ajaxValidation` with file uploads see [**`here`**](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6873)

Comment: Yes you are correct, but solution that you've linked me is not clearly solved. When someone is using AJAX for entire form can find problem with file input, and they recommend to use widget (client side validation)what is in basic case not necessary because Yii2 is doing that automatically. Please read my post again because I am not using ajaxValidation for file, as it's written above 'unique fields'.

Comment: yes i agree that you should use the widget like `\kartik\FileInput` to upload on runtime, but the OP has added the notes that he is not using any widget other than standard file input provided by `ActiveForm`, the reason to comment was so that you should not get down votes. Just mention in the top of your post and all is good.Cheers!